# Stata: How do I check whether the value of one variable exists somewhere in the column of another variable?

Tags: variables, stata, check-constraints

I have two variables in Stata  which are string (`MAIDCW1` and `strboth`).

I would like to check for each observation whether the value of `MAIDCW1` exists somewhere in the whole of `strboth`. If this value exists in the variable, I would like to set the variable `TreatmentFinal` to 1, otherwise to 0.

I tried the following code variants but I always receive the error code "invalid syntax":

```
**Variant 1:**

gen TreatmentFinal = 0
forvalues i = 1 / _N {

    quietly count if strboth == MAIDCW1
    
    if r(N) > 0 {
        replace TreatmentFinal = 1 in `i'
    } else {
        replace TreatmentFinal = 0 in `i'
    }
}


**Variant 2:**

gen TreatmentFinal = 0
forvalues i = 1 / _N {

    qui gen match = cond(index(strboth, MAIDCW1[`i']) > 0, 1, 0)
    
    replace TreatmentFinal = match in `i'
   
    drop match
}
```

I also tried to first format `strboth` and `MAIDCW1` as strings, but this does not change the result and I still receive the error code "invalid syntax".

**Addendum:**

1.) I use an Excel dataset and randomize a market ID to a treatment (1) & control group (0). So, the variable Treatment is either 1 or 0.

2.) I merge the market ID (e.g., 046914YBB) and Treatment which becomes strboth (e.g., 046914YBB1).

3.) Now I look at a different column which has several entries of the same market ID (for different calender weeks) and add "1" to all of them in order to compare it to strboth, which would indicate whether it belongs to the treatment group (as the market ID entry in strboth also has a "1" at the end) or to the control group (if the entry has a "0" at the end). This variable then is MAIDCW1. Entries with the same marked IDs should always be in the same group (either treatment or control).

4.) Then, for all entries of MAIDCW1 I check whether the value also exists in strboth in order to define for all market IDs of the different calendar weeks whether they belong to the treatment or control group (TreamtentFinal). -> And here the problem of Nick's code appears: The same entries of market IDs for different calendar weeks (entries in MAIDCW1) receive different values in TreatmentFinal (0 or 1) even though they all should have the same value.

Here is the complete code including Nick’s suggestion:

```
clear
  import excel "Example.xlsx", sheet("Example") firstrow

set seed 123
bysort MarktName: gen double rand1=rnormal() if _n==1
egen max1=max(rand1), by(MarktName)
replace rand1=max1

bysort AbteilungName: gen double rand2=rnormal() if _n==1
egen max2=max(rand2), by(AbteilungName)
replace rand2=max2

sort rand1 rand2

// Randomization pattern
gen Randomisierung =
```

"111000011100001110000111100011110001111000011100001110000111100011"

```
// Assignment to treatment (1) or control group (0) 
gen Treatment = substr(Randomisierung, _n, 1)

drop Randomisierung

//Here the relevant part begins:

gen TreatmentFinal = 0 
gen strboth = MAID + Treatment
gen long obsno = _n 
egen long group = group(strboth) 
su group, meanonly  
local G = r(max) 

quietly forval g = 1/`G' { 
    su obsno if group == `g', meanonly 
    count if strboth[r(min)] == MAIDCW1 
    if r(N) > 0 replace TreatmentFinal = 1 if group == `g' 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work. I doubt it's very good Stata style, and someone else may think of a better approach, but let's get you closer to something that works. Some people would see this as a problem for `merge`.

What we should do is loop over the distinct values of `strboth` and NOT repeat comparisons for each observation with the same value.

EDIT: Note the emphasis here. If 42 occurs repeatedly in one variable, then checking whether it occurs in the other variable need only be done once. You should read the help for `group()` in `help egen`: it maps the distinct values of its argument(s) to integers 1 up. So distinct strings `frog newt toad` would be mapped to `1 2 3`.

```
gen TreatmentFinal = 0 
gen long obsno = _n 
egen long group = group(strboth) 
su group, meanonly  
local G = r(max) 

quietly forval g = 1/`G' { 
    su obsno if group == `g', meanonly 
    count if strboth[r(min)] == MAIDCW1 
    if r(N) > 0 replace TreatmentFinal = 1 if group == `g' 
}
```

EDIT: Don't be misled by the option name `meanonly`. `summarize` is used here to get the *minimum* as a safe way to look up the value of one variable indexed by each distinct value of `group`.

Mistakes in your code:

1. `forvalues` won't evaluate `_N` on the fly.
2. Looping over observations doesn't itself imply focus on a particular observation each time around the loop.
3. The display format of strings is not relevant to this problem.

Other points:

4. There is no need to `replace` 0 with 0.
5. 

```
cond(index(strboth, MAIDCW1[`i']) > 0, 1, 0)
```

is equivalent to

```
index(strboth, MAIDCW1[`i']) > 0`
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response and especially for pointing out the mistakes in my code, Nick!

However, unfortunately, your suggestion did not lead to the desired outcome yet. Maybe to specify the problem a little further and also to explain the steps I did before, I added additional information to my original request as an addendum. I hope everything is explained clearly - again, thank you so much for helping me out!

Comment: Thanks for the thanks.  I have to conclude that I don't understand the problem fully so I will leave it there.

Comment: Fair enough, I totally understand that thanks anyway! Maybe you could still clarify a few questions regarding your code:
Why do we iterate through several groups? Why do we have several groups in the first place and what values are part of the different groups? And why do we calculate the mean here? 
As far as I understand, we only should have one group which includes all values of strboth. And for each row of MAIDCW1 it should be checked whether this value also exists in this one group of strboth, no? Once again, thank you very much for your support!

Comment: I've added some emphasis and extra explanation in the answer.